# Difference between running java program using jar file or installing onto a system using Izpack?

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

is there a difference between using my java program as a jar file as opposed to using a software like IzPack to create an installer and install it onto a system ? Does it make any difference performance wise and what are some benefits ( if any) of going either way ( aside from creating shortcuts) ?

Comment: It does not make any difference performance-wise

Comment: i dont know anything about lzPack but the JavaFX "native" compilation target (bundle) will enhance performance somewhat -- shorter loading times and such ... you wont notice much with hello-word apps though, the difference starts to become visible after several hundred implemented classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jar directly allows it to be used in other machines.
If you were to use IzPack to create an installer, it will still work in other systems after installation.
As far as I know, there is none performance-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague.

Some tools like WinRun4J can be helpful to optimize the amount of memory available for your program at startup. WinRun4J and PackR allow to use a custom name for the executable which is useful if you want to hide the fact that your program uses Java.

Some web browsers under some operating systems break the downloaded JARs by wrapping them in ZIPs for "security purposes".

Some tools use a fat JAR in input and produce a kind a native bundle which is more familiar for the end users, PackR and JNDT produce APP files for OS X, JNDT produce RPM and DEB packages for GNU Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Whether it is a jar file or Izpack installed java app, there won't be any performance difference.

The main differentiator I see is the user experience. For simple applications it doesn't make much difference. But for any medium to large scale application which needs to perform some prerequisite checks, capture configuration data from user, upgrade the application etc, installer helps a lot in making installation more user-friendly.

So using Izpack or in any installer in general, improves the user experience. Some of them I can think of are:

1. Installer can perform any software prerequisite checks before
   installing the application.
2. Allows user to choose the installation location
3. Prompts for any required input parameters or configuration and validating it
4. Allows the user to enter these input or configuration data
5. Upgrades the software by taking care of any data software or data/configuration migrating and ensures proper rollback in case of
   failures.

Without the installer most of these need manual intervention and installation becomes more error prone, manual errors and becomes a tedious job for the user.